# Google Cloud Endpoints SPI restricted

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I defined a simple API using Google Cloud Endpoints:

```
@Api(name = "realestate", version = "v1")
public class RealEstatePropertyV1 {

    @ApiMethod(name = "properties", httpMethod = "GET")
    public List<RealEstateProperty> list() {
        return ofy().load().type(RealEstateProperty.class).list();
    }
}
```

I also configured `web.xml`:

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value>com.realestate.api.v1.RealEstatePropertyV1</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I launch the API in eclipse and execute `curl http://localhost:8888/_ah/spi/realestate/v1/properties`. The response is

```
<html><head><title>Error 405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL</title></head>
<body><h2>Error 405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL</h2></body>
</html>
```

The server log is:

```
Jun 20, 2013 9:22:14 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Jun 20, 2013 9:22:29 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet init
INFO: SPI restricted: true
```

Do you know what does `SPI restricted` means? I'd like to mention that I did not register anything in the Google API console. My goal is to first test the API locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test your application, try

```
curl -X POST -d "{}" \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
> http://localhost:8888/_ah/spi/realestate/v1/properties
```

Better yet, test your application using the APIs explorer

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer
```

As for `SPI restricted` in your logs, this just indicates whether or not that method has auth set up. In your case, for this method, it was `true`.

Comment: Using your `curl` command, i get the following: `{"error_message":"missing /{Service}.{method}"}`. I did not deploy the API on App Engine, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: That will have nothing to do with `localhost:8888`. What is `{Service}`?

Comment: Since I did not specify a `path` attribute to `@ApiMethod`, the correct URL is `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/realestate/v1/realestateproperty`. I got it from the API explorer. At first it did not work because I was using `objectify` which seems not to work with endpoints.

Comment: Feel free to post issues you're having getting Objectify working with Endpoints. We're happy to help.

Comment: In one of my entity I have a field `@Parent Ref<Owner>`, it seems that `Ref` is not handled because if I have this field, I can't generate client libraries and nothing is working. I use `Objectify 4`

Comment: (I meant post a new question.)

Comment: Hi, i am getting the same error when i call the endpoints from java script. is there anything enable/disable ?

Comment: I also get {"error_message":"missing /{Service}.{method}"} for some reason. I'm using curl to do a post request with no data. Using the same url it shows in the api explorer after it does the post request. Am i missing anything here?